# Stub api with static methods

Tags: apex, unit-test, static, mock, stubapi

I have a global class with a static method which makes post callout and I want to use `Stub API`, but I don't get how to do it when a method is static. I understand what to do inside mock classes, but I don't know how to call them. Here is my code:

```
global with sharing class UsersHelper {
global static String getAdminUser() { 
 //callout
 return  string;
}
}

@isTest
public class MockProvider implements System.StubProvider {
    public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName,
        Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, List<String> listOfParamNames,
        List<Object> listOfArgs) {
        System.debug(stubbedMethodName);
        System.debug(stubbedObject);


        if (stubbedMethodName == 'getAdminUser') {
            //set response, etc
            return adminUser;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}


public class MockUtil {
    private MockUtil(){}

    public static MockProvider getInstance() {
        return new MockProvider();
    }

    public static Object createMock(Type typeToMock) {
        return Test.createStub(typeToMock, MockUtil.getInstance());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to mock a static method using `Stub API`.
Please take a look at the [Build a Mocking Framework with the Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) documentation.

You can’t mock the following Apex elements.

- **Static methods (including future methods)**
- Private methods
- Properties (getters and setters)
- Triggers
- Inner classes
- System types
- Classes that implement the Batchable interface
- Classes that have only private constructors

Comment: Oh, thanks. I read that but didnt look into limitations .